# SSL/TLS error code 18 "self signed certificate" on heroku postgres connection

Tags: ssl, rust, heroku-postgres

I have a free tier heroku Rust app that connects to a Heroku postgres instance on the `hobby-dev` tier (lowest tier) using the library [rust-postgres](https://crates.io/crates/postgres). When my app tries to make an SSL/TLS connection to the postgres instance, it fails with the error

`self signed certificate`

and error code 18. I did not supply this self-signed cert, it would automatically provisioned by Heroku when I provisioned the Heroku postgres instance.

What can I do to heroku, or the `rust-postgres` function which makes the connection, so that I can successfully connect to the Postgres instance?